# Evaluating expression :- Javascript vs Python

Tags: javascript, python

The following expression results different result in Javascript in Python and Javascript:-

Python:-

```
a, b, c, e, f, h = 271733878, 4023233417, 5858469028, -389564586, 2562383102, 1634886000

a = a + (c & b | ~c & f) + h + e  # 4965557782
```

Javascript:-

```js
a = 271733878;
b = 4023233417;
c = 5858469028;
e = -389564586
f = 2562383102;
h = 1634886000;

a = a + (c & b | ~c & f) + h + e; // 670590486

console.log(a)
```

How is the evaluation of the same expression differ in 2 languages?

Comment: because they are written differently?

Comment: Even evaluating the mathematical expressions? that sounds weird!! Should be something more.

Comment: Bitwise calculations always depend on the bit representation of the value, and are thereby very specific to the language/platform used. There isn't really any one "right" answer.

Comment: Found the solution. Converting the python number to 32-bit works.

Answer (score 2):

`~c` is evaluated differently in Python and Javascript.

`~c` is the negation of the c value. This is done by inverting the bits of the value. As such, the value differs in different languages because they probably use a different amount of bits to store int values, which will result in a different ~value.

Javascript:

```
~c = -1563501733
```

Python:

```
~c = -5858469029
```

Comment: Any solution to this, for me to make it behave similarly?

Comment: Converting the python number to 32-bit works.

Comment: Yep, that was what I was about to suggest! Glad you found your answer